# How to get dropdown clicked item value angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ajax

I created a function name is rate. When the page load the function is working. Ajax method is getting result from API. When the function done ng-repeat is working correctly. Later when I click dropdown menu item the function is running, but I want to get clicked dropdown menu item value to insert {{status.value}}. Also I have a different problem. When the loop is working browser is freezing. How can I solve this problem?

**HTML code**

```
<div class="analysisItem col-sm-6" ng-if="status">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="dropdown">
            <div class="analysisbutton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="a col-12">Arz<br><span class="value">{{status.value}}</span><span class="dropdown-arrow"></span></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="dropdown-menu w-100">
                <a class="dropdown-item" ng-repeat="i in statusRes" data-type="status" data-value="{{i.valueint}}" ng-click="rate();">{{i.value}} <span class="float-right">%{{i.factor}}</span></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS code**

```
$scope.type = ["status", "category", "subCategory", "room", "buildingAge", "sfloor", "floor", "square", "price", "currency", "value", "feedback"];
$scope.rate = function (type) {
    if (type) $scope.type[type] = type;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.type.length; i++) {
        setTimeout(function (i) {
                $scope.params = {
                    lat: $scope.lat,
                    lng: $scope.lng,
                    time: $scope.time,
                    type: $scope.type[i]
                }

            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                url: "index.php",
                dataType: 'json',
                async: false,
                cache: false,
                xhrFields: {
                    withCredentials: true
                },
                data: $scope.params,
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.response) {
                        if ($scope.type[i] == "status") {
                            if (data.response == null || data.response == "") {

                            } else {
                                $scope.status = data.response[0];
                                $scope.statusRes = data.response;
                            }                                    
                        } 

                        if ($scope.type[i] == "category") {
                            if (data.response == null || data.response == "") {

                            } else {
                                $scope.category = data.response[0];
                                $scope.categoryRes = data.response;
                            }
                        }                                

                        if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();
                    } else if (data.response == null) {

                    } else if (data.error) {

                    }
                },
                error: function (data) {
                }
            });
        }, i * 2000, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: there are number of things wrong with your code. why you are using $.ajax instead of $http and you are using ajax inside for loop. that's why your browse is freezing.

Comment: I have to send until type array values ajax request. What is the best method?

Comment: prepare your array in for loop and post of all of them in one $http request. process it in server accordingly.

Comment: I have to use array orderly. For example first ajax request is getting a result then the returning result values is using second step.  So I used type: $scope.type[i].

Comment: if the result is returned from the server, you can do the same loop on server side.

Comment: I get different result for every request and I have to show every result orderly.